# Is there a way to provide an external link to an enterprise sharepoint from an external site?

Tags: sharepoint

I have an outward facing website(non SharePoint), that I would like to include a link in to an enterprise SharePoint. Does SharePoint allow validated users to enter from an external website and if so does SharePoint have a way to generate that link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports windows authentication so both sites using windows authentication will allow validated users to enter from an external website.